# Any smart method to get exp/html back after Go1?

Tags: go

I've installed the Go release version as root.
Go1 removed all exp/ code.

Is there smart method to get exp/* back after Go1?
(I mean how to install in my local GOPATH?)

[My Solution]

```
# pull from go repository to $HOME/repo/go
cd $HOME/repo
hg clone https://go.googlecode.com/hg/go
# make symbolic link to your GOPATH(eg. $HOME/go)
cd $HOME/go/src
ln -s $HOME/repo/go/src/pkg/exp .
```

Comment: Note: go 1.4 (Q4 2014) will change the url again: see [my answer below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26773479/6309).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: with go 1.4 (Q4, 2014), [the url for that `exp` package will change (again)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/golang-announce/eD8dh3T9yyA):

```
code.google.com/p/go.exp => golang.org/x/exp
```

That means now:

```
go get golang.org/x/exp
```

See "[Go 1.4 subrepo renaming](http://golang.org/s/go14subrepo)".

Regarding the `html` package, it is in `net/html`, so this will become (as commented by [andybalholm](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1097065/andybalholm)):

```
go get golang.org/x/net/html
```

Comment: The html package is in net now, not exp.

Answer (score 5):

The exp/html library was incomplete which is why it was removed for Go1.

However if you really want to use it then

```
go get code.google.com/p/go/src/pkg/exp/html
```

may install it back for you. If you want a *slightly* more complete html parser then you might checkout http://code.google.com/p/go-html-transform/ as well it has an html5 parser as well as a css selector based scraping and transformation library.

**EDIT**: Apparently trying to go get the package that way doesn't really work. It appears the only way to install this is to checkout the go source code and then install from source. This is actually a really quick an painless process if you want to go that route.

Comment: `go get code.google.com/p/go/src/pkg/exp/html` got error messages as: package code.google.com/p/go/src/pkg/exp/html
imports code.google.com/p/go/src/pkg/exp/html
imports code.google.com/p/go/src/pkg/exp/html: import code.google.com/p/go/src/pkg/exp/html": **cannot find package**

Comment: Could you add some document on the main site of go-html-transform.  Especial example code and how to 'go get your package'.

Comment: Ugh, I hadn't actually tried to get exp/html that way myself. That's too bad. I'll see about adding more documentation for html transform to it's project page.

Comment: FYI: The author of exp/html is nearly ready to release a complete version so this may get a lot easier soon.

Answer (score 2):

[Building from source](http://golang.org/doc/install/source) is the way to do this.  When you do the `hg update` step though, note that since the exp tree is not tagged go1, that `hg update release` won't get it for you.  Instead `hg update weekly` will get it, and is probably what you want.

Edit: Weekly releases were discontinued after Go 1, so `hg update weekly` will access increasingly stale code.  A better strategy is `hg update tip`, then copy the exp directory or directories of interest somewhere and recompile it with whatever Go version you are using, Go 1.0.1, for example.

Answer (score 0):

### This answer is outdated.

This is covered in the golang wiki:

https://code.google.com/p/go-wiki/wiki/InstallingExp

```
% cd $GOPATH/src
% hg clone https://code.google.com/p/go go-exp
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
added 13323 changesets with 50185 changes to 7251 files (+5 heads)
updating to branch default
3464 files updated, 0 files merged, 0 files removed, 0 files unresolved
% mv go-exp/src/pkg/exp .
% rm -rf go-exp
% go install exp/...
```

Then, to use it:

```
import "exp/proxy"
```

I tried this a few months ago and it worked pretty well. Also, when I ran `go install ...` I limited it to only the package I was interested in: `go install exp/html` (if I recall, correctly).

Comment: Answer is changed because I think this maybe the official method.

Answer (score 0):

The exp packages have been moved to different repositories now, to make them easier to install. Now you can install the former exp/html with go get "golang.org/x/net/html".