# Whitelist tags exempt from escaping using Go's html/template

Tags: templates, go

Pass a []byte into a template as the body of a message post on a forum-style web app. In the template, call a method to convert to string and along the way, switch out all newlines for line breaks:

```
<p>{{.BodyString}}</p>
```

...

```
func (p *Post) BodyString() string {
    nl := regexp.MustCompile(`\n`)
    return nl.ReplaceAllString(string(p.Body), `<br>`)
}
```

What you'll end up with:

```
paragraphs <br> <br>in <br> <br>this <br> <br>post
```

I don't want to pass the entire post in with HTML(p.Body), as it represents third party data from potentially untrustworthy sources. Is there a way to whitelist only some tags for formatting purposes using the vanilla Go1 template package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do think you want to parse the HTML.  The HTML parser in exp/html was deemed incomplete and so removed from Go 1, although the exp tree is still in the Go source tree and can be accessed by weekly tag, for example.  I don't know exactly what is incomplete.  I used it for a simple task once and it met my needs.

Also of course, check the [dashboard](http://godashboard.appspot.com/) and see related SO post, [Any smart method to get exp/html back after Go1?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9986329/any-smart-method-to-get-exp-html-back-after-go1/), mostly for the recomendation of http://code.google.com/p/go-html-transform/

Comment: At one time it failed when it encountered javascript tags with a '<' in them. I don't know if it still does or not but the code is full of TODO items for various parts of the html parsing spec.

Comment: Thank you, I  will investigate go-html-transform. After all, Go needs its very own BeautifulSoup...

Comment: Patches are welcome for go-html-transform as well if you find it needs some tweaking :-)

Answer (score 1):

I'm affraid the template package cannot help with this too much. If you want to remove specific (black-listed) tags (resp. the sub-tree enclosed by such tags) or allow to pass only specific tags (white-listed) then I think probably nothing less than parsing and rewriting the html AST can be a good solution. That said, one can see here and there some crazy REs trying to do the same, but I don't consider that a "good solution" and I doubt they can be a "correct" solution in the general case of a specs conforming HTML, including several legal irregularities, as it is probably ruled out of a regular grammar category problem.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt answer. I selected Sonia's but yours was useful too.