# Using go-html-transform to preprocess HTML: Replace fails

Tags: html-parsing, go

Following on from [this question on whitelisting HTML tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10025292/whitelist-tags-exempt-from-escaping-using-gos-html-template), I've been experimenting with Jeremy Wall's [go-html-transform](http://code.google.com/p/go-html-transform/). In the hopes of improving searchable documentation I'm asking this here rather than pestering the author directly... hopefully this isn't too tool-specific for SO.

App Engine, latest SDK. Post.Body is a []byte. This works:

```
package posts

import (
    // ...      
    "html/template"
    "code.google.com/p/go-html-transform/html/transform"
    "code.google.com/p/go-html-transform/h5"
)

// ...

// Pre-process post body, then return it to the template as HTML()
// to avoid html/template's escaping allowable tags
func (p *Post) BodyHTML() template.HTML {
    doc, _ := transform.NewDoc(string(p.Body))
    t := transform.NewTransform(doc)

    // Add some text to the end of any <strong></strong> nodes.
    t.Apply(transform.AppendChildren(h5.Text("<em>Foo</em>")), "strong")
    return template.HTML(t.String())
}
```

Result:

```
<strong>Blarg.<em>Foo</em></strong>
```

However, if instead of AppendChildren() I use something like the following:

```
t.Apply(transform.Replace(h5.Text("<em>Foo</em>")), "strong")
```

I get an internal server error. Have I misunderstood the use of Replace()? [The existing documentation](http://code.google.com/p/go-html-transform/source/browse/html/transform/transform.go) suggests this sort of thing should be possible.

Comment: Can you add an issue with the panic that occurs? You have probably uncovered a bug.

Comment: actually I've already isolated the problem to a test case and committed the fix. Assuming you are running into the problem I think you are. see: http://code.google.com/p/go-html-transform/source/detail?r=941f7061b6cd9c3c3666f6da3554cdb9d211b539 for the code that fixes it.

Comment: and yes, works fine now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Running your transform code outside of App Engine, it panics and you can see a TODO in the source at that point.  Then it's not too much harder to read the code and see that it's going to panic if given a root node.

Comment: yeah I've been meaning to get to that todo for a while. This gave me the needed push to do so. Just pushed the fix.

Comment: I'm glad you could tell that from reading the source Sonia, I'm afraid I'm not that clever! Good thought to run it through a non-GAE Go, I guess that's one of the drawbacks of using App Engine as your sandbox.