# Extract links from a web page using Go lang

Tags: html-parsing, go

I am learning [google's Go programming language](http://golang.org/). Does anyone know the best practice to extract all URLs from a html web page?

Coming from the Java world, there are libraries to do the job, for example [jsoup](http://jsoup.org/) , [htmlparser](http://htmlparser.sourceforge.net/), etc. But for go lang, I guess no available similar library was made yet?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Go's standard package for HTML parsing is still a work in progress and is not part of the current release.  A third party package you might try though is [go-html-transform](http://code.google.com/p/go-html-transform/).  It is being actively maintained.

Comment: I can't find an example anywhere on how to use this library for scraping and don't find it obvious from the docs. Could anyone point me to an example?

Comment: Is it planned to include this package natively in Go?

Comment: The HTML package is now available. Read the documentation here:
https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net/html

Answer (score 26):

If you know jQuery, you'll love [GoQuery](https://github.com/PuerkitoBio/goquery).

Honestly, it's the easiest, most powerful HTML utility I've found in Go, and it's based off of the html package in the go.net repository. (Okay, so it's higher-level than just a parser as it doesn't expose raw HTML tokens and the like, but if you want to actually get anything done with an HTML document, this package will help.)

Answer (score 17):

While the Go package for HTML parsing is indeed still in progress, it is available in the [go.net](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.net/html) repository.

Its sources are at <del>[`code.google.com/p/go.net/html`](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse?repo=net#hg%2Fhtml)</del> [`github.com/golang/net`](https://github.com/golang/net) and it is being actively developed.

It is mentioned in this recent [go-nuts discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/golang-nuts/zf-N0Y1733o/discussion).

---

Note that with Go 1.4 (Dec 2014), as I mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26773479/6309), the package is now `golang.org/x/net` (see [godoc](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/net)).

Comment: The Go html package has move to the [go.net](https://code.google.com/p/go/source/browse?repo=net#hg%2Fhtml) repo. [Here](http://godoc.org/code.google.com/p/go.net/html) is the documentation.

Comment: @ctn thank you for the update. Not sure why your edit was rejected: I have restored it in the answer.

Comment: Thanks. They said it would change the original meaning too much and I'd better leave a comment instead.

Answer (score 6):

I've searched around and found that there are is a library called [Gokogiri](https://github.com/moovweb/gokogiri) which sounds alike Nogokiri for Ruby. I think the project is [active](https://github.com/moovweb/gokogiri/graphs/commit-activity) too.

Answer (score 0):

I just published an open source event-based HTML 5.0 compliant parsing package for Go. You can [find it here](https://github.com/calbucci/go-htmlparser)

Here is the sample code to get all the links from a page (from A elements):

```
links := make([]string)

parser := NewParser(htmlContent)

parser.Parse(nil, func(e *HtmlElement, isEmpty bool) {
    if e.TagName == "link" {
        link,_ := e.GetAttributeValue("href")
        if(link != "") {
            links = appends(links, link)
        } 
    }
}, nil)
```

A few things to keep in mind:

- These are relative links, not full URLs
- Dynamically generated links will not be collected
- There are other links not being collected (META tags, images, iframes, etc.). It's pretty easy to modify this code to collect those.

Answer (score 0):

also you may use ["Colly"](https://github.com/gocolly/colly) ([documentations](http://www.go-colly.org/docs/)),
it usually use for web scrapping

**Features**

1. Clean API
2. Fast (>1k request/sec on a single core)
3. Manages request delays and maximum concurrency per domain
4. Automatic cookie and session handling
5. Sync/async/parallel scraping
6. Distributed scraping
7. Caching
8. Automatic encoding of non-unicode responses
9. Robots.txt support
10. Google App Engine support

```
import (
   "fmt"
   "github.com/gocolly/colly"
)

func main() {
   c := colly.NewCollector()
 
   // Find and visit all links
   c.OnHTML("a", func(e *colly.HTMLElement) {
     e.Request.Visit(e.Attr("href"))
   })
 
   c.OnRequest(func(r *colly.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Visiting", r.URL)
   })

   c.Visit("http://go-colly.org/")
}
```