# Golang Webapp Seed Set up fails

Tags: git, go

I am follow the steps in https://auth0.com/docs/server-platforms/golang
and trying to setup the seed project on a Windows 7 box .

I have **ABLE** to do "go get " for the following;

```
github.com/gorilla/mux, golang.org/x/oauth2,github.com/astaxie/beego/session,
get github.com/codegangsta/negroni
```

After these when i run go install i get the **error**;

```
C:\Users\TestUser\Documents\go\auth0-golang-sample>go install
main.go:4:2: cannot find package "github.com/auth0/auth0-go/examples/regular-web-app/app" in any of: C:\Go\src\pkg\github.com\auth0\auth0-go\examples\regular-web-app\app (from $GOROOT)
        C:\Users\TestUser\Documents\go\src\github.com\auth0\auth0-go\examples\regular-web-app\app (
from $GOPATH)
server.go:4:2: cannot find package "github.com/auth0/auth0-go/examples/regular-web-app/routes/callback" in any of: C:\Go\src\pkg\github.com\auth0\auth0-go\examples\regular-web-app\routes\callback (from $GOROOT)
.....
.....
```

I get the error below when i try  " go get github.com/auth0/auth0-go/"

```
C:\Users\TestUser\Documents\go\auth0-golang-sample>go get github.com/auth0/auth0-go/
Username for 'https://github.com': user
Password for 'https://user@github.com':
# cd .; git clone https://github.com/auth0/auth0-go C:\Users\TestUser\Documents\go\src\github.com\a
uth0\auth0-go
Cloning into 'C:\Users\TestUser\Documents\go\src\github.com\auth0\auth0-go'...
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/auth0/auth0-go/' not found
package github.com/auth0/auth0-go: exit status 128
```

However when i try **go get github.com/auth0/auth0-golang/**

```
C:\Users\TestUser\Documents\go\auth0-golang-sample>go get github.com/auth0/auth0-golang/
package github.com/auth0/auth0-golang
        imports github.com/auth0/auth0-golang
        imports github.com/auth0/auth0-golang: no buildable Go source files in C:\Users\TestUser\Documents\go\src\github.com\auth0\auth0-golang
```

The files/folders created however in

```
C:\Users\TestUser\Documents\go\src\github.com\auth0\auth0-golang\
+--examples
  +--go-api
     --main.go
     --README.md
  +--regular-web-app
     +--app
        --app.go
     +--public
        --app.css
        --app.js
     +--routes
        +--CALLBACK
        +--home
        +--middlewares
        +--user
         --templates.go
      --main.go
      --README.md
      --server.go
--.gitignore
--README.md
```

Below are my go env

```
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=C:\Users\TestUser\Documents\go\bin
set GOCHAR=6
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\TestUser\Documents\go
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=C:\Go
set GOTOOLDIR=C:\Go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set CC=gcc
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
```

I have been locked with this issue for days, any help will be much appreciated.
Thanks to @Vonc i've overcome initial huddle.
Now `go install` spits this error

```
# github.com/auth0/auth0-golang/examples/regular-web-app/routes/callback
..\src\github.com\auth0\auth0-golang\examples\regular-web-app\routes\callback\ca
llback.go:17: undefined: oauth2.New
..\src\github.com\auth0\auth0-golang\examples\regular-web-app\routes\callback\ca
llback.go:18: undefined: oauth2.Client
..\src\github.com\auth0\auth0-golang\examples\regular-web-app\routes\callback\ca
llback.go:19: undefined: oauth2.RedirectURL
```

i have already `go get golang.org/x/oauth2'
and the result(simplified)...

```
C:\Users\TestUser\Documents\go\
+--pkg
   +--windows_amd64
    +--golang.org
        +--x
           +--net
           +--oauth2
               --internal.a
               --jws.a
            --oauth2.a
+--src
  +--golang.org
    +--x
        +--net
        +--oauth2
```

I have scrubbed all and installed go 1.4 but i still error 
undefined oauth2.New, oauth2.Client etc

I had no luck with go get github.com/golang/oauth2 result

```
can't load package: package github.com/golang/oauth2: code in directory C:\Users
\TestUser\Documents\go\src\github.com\golang\oauth2 expects import "golang.org/x/oauth2"
```

Am really stuck in a quagmire

**I just found the answer to the golang auth issue, this is as a  result of code changes [link to code](https://github.com/golang/oauth2/commit/9b6b7610ad5cd4b1b578a11438aaa693e36c5db9)**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've just updated the Docs and the [Sample](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-golang/tree/master/examples/regular-web-app).

There were 2 errors:

1) Package rename
2) OAuth2 package completely changed its API so I've updated it to work as intended.

Now, you should be able to do a go get of the project, or just download it into `$GO_PATH/src/github.com/auth0` and then do `go get .`, `go run main.go server.go` and it should work.

Let me know if it does!

Comment: Great feedback frol the author himself. +1. More precise that my answer which was more a guesswork.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the repo has been renamed from `auth0/auth0-go` to: [`auth0/auth0-golang`](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-golang/)

You can see that wrong import in [`auth0/auth0-golang/examples/regular-web-app/main.go`](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-golang/blob/master/examples/regular-web-app/main.go), and the app package does exist, but in [`auth0/auth0-golang/examples/regular-web-app/app/app.go`](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-golang/blob/master/examples/regular-web-app/app/app.go)

```
package main

import (
    "github.com/auth0/auth0-go/examples/regular-web-app/app"
    "github.com/joho/godotenv"
    "log"
)
```

A Pull Request would allow that repo to fix the wrong import.

---

Regarding the oauth error:

```
# github.com/auth0/auth0-golang/examples/regular-web-app/routes/callback
..\src\github.com\auth0\auth0-golang\examples\regular-web-app\routes\callback\callback.go:17:
undefined: oauth2.New
```

`go get golang.org/x/oauth2` isn't enough
`go get github.com/golang/oauth2` should work better, considering, as the OP mentions, that it was recently fixed in order to take into account the [package change from `net/yyy` to `golang/x/yyyy`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26773479/6309) (see [commit 9b6b761](https://github.com/golang/oauth2/commit/9b6b7610ad5cd4b1b578a11438aaa693e36c5db9)).

Comment: VonC,thanks. As i stated, i tried to import **go get github.com/auth0/auth0-golang/** and i got the error just before the go env upstairs. Should i manually copy the cloned files into the `C:\Users\TestUser\Do
cuments\go\src\github.com\auth0\auth0-golang` or rather allow the **go get** to resolve that. Thanks

Comment: @BlowMan a manual copy would work, provided you *also* fix the `regular-web-app/main.go` import referencing the `app` package. Or the error would persists.

Comment: thanks i did as suggested and cleared error. I have updated the question with another error when i `go install`.

Comment: @BlowMan `golang.org/x/oauth2` looks like an 1.4 path (http://stackoverflow.com/a/26773479/6309) Are you using go1.4?

Comment: @BlowMan considering https://github.com/golang/oauth2, did you try a `go get github.com/golang/oauth2`? (in addition of the `go get golang.org/x/oauth2`)

Comment: go version 1.3.3.  i tried only go get golang.org/x/oauth2 .  i did not try go get github.com/golang/oauth2. Thanks

Comment: @BlowMan Ok. Try the second `go get github.com/golang/oauth2` then. If any issue persists, consider using go1.4 as well just in case it helps.

Comment: I found the answer after a little combing, it relates to code changes and i have updated the question. Thanks

Comment: @BlowMan Ok, I have included your conclusions in the answer for more visibility.