# How to get system information in Go?

Tags: go

Can anyone recommend a module which can be used to get system information, like Python's `psutil`?

When I tried `>go get github.com/golang/sys get 'sys'`, I received the following:

```
Report Error:
package github.com/golang/sys
        imports github.com/golang/sys
        imports github.com/golang/sys: no buildable Go source files in D:\go_source\src\github.com\golang\sys
```

This my system environment:

```
# native compiler windows amd64

GOROOT=D:\Go
#GOBIN=
GOARCH=amd64
GOOS=windows
CGO_ENABLED=1

PATH=c:\mingw64\bin;%GOROOT%\bin;%PATH%

LITEIDE_GDB=gdb64
LITEIDE_MAKE=mingw32-make
LITEIDE_TERM=%COMSPEC%
LITEIDE_TERMARGS=
LITEIDE_EXEC=%COMSPEC%
LITEIDE_EXECOPT=/C
```

Comment: Can you try with `go get golang.org/x/sys/windows`? I have updated the answer.

Answer (score 7):

This is a simple **Windows** example to extract the Hostname, Platform, CPU model, total RAM and disk capacity. First install the module:

```
go get github.com/shirou/gopsutil
```

I had problems with the installation and I also had to install:

```
go get github.com/StackExchange/wmi
```

Now run this code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/cpu"
    "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/disk"
    "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/host"
    "github.com/shirou/gopsutil/mem"
)

// SysInfo saves the basic system information
type SysInfo struct {
    Hostname string `bson:hostname`
    Platform string `bson:platform`
    CPU      string `bson:cpu`
    RAM      uint64 `bson:ram`
    Disk     uint64 `bson:disk`
}

func main() {
    hostStat, _ := host.Info()
    cpuStat, _ := cpu.Info()
    vmStat, _ := mem.VirtualMemory()
    diskStat, _ := disk.Usage("\\") // If you're in Unix change this "\\" for "/"

    info := new(SysInfo)

    info.Hostname = hostStat.Hostname
    info.Platform = hostStat.Platform
    info.CPU = cpuStat[0].ModelName
    info.RAM = vmStat.Total / 1024 / 1024
    info.Disk = diskStat.Total / 1024 / 1024

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", info)

}
```

Answer (score 5):

You would need actually to do ([following godoc](https://godoc.org/golang.org/x/sys)):

```
go get golang.org/x/sys/unix
# or
go get golang.org/x/sys/windows
# or
go get golang.org/x/sys/plan9
```

(depending on your OS)

Comment: The golang.org/x reflects the new organization (http://stackoverflow.com/a/26773479/6309)

Comment: go get golang.org/x/sys...   (ellipses) seems to work on my machine

Comment: @Uvelichitel yes, but do you actually need all three?

Answer (score 4):

I know this is an old post, but putting this out there for others who can benefit.

exactly what you're looking for here:

https://github.com/shirou/gopsutil